# Wikis de tag copiados do Wikipédia?

Tags: debate, tags

Algumas pessoas têm copiado conteúdo do Wikipédia para colocar nas wikis de tag ([exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/70)). Como devemos lidar com isso?

Discussão no SO em inglês: [Copy and pasting Wikipedia articles into tag-wikis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81047/copy-and-pasting-wikipedia-articles-into-tag-wikis)

Comment: E pegar do Stackoverflow?

Answer (score 7):

Até usando o mesmo critério adotado no SO original, acho que não há problema em usar o conteúdo da Wikipedia, mas colar o conteúdo integral não funciona.

A intenção da *tag wiki* é dar uma informação básica sobre o assunto, oferecer caminhos alternativos para quem está iniciando no assunto obter informações básicas antes de perguntar e possivelmente indicar que tipo de pergunta deve usar a *tag*. Em geral o conteúdo da Wikipedia, na forma original, não costuma ser bom para isso.

Além disso, tanto para o fragmento quanto para o texto mais completo, o artigo na Wikipedia deve ser muito longo.

Usar alguma frase da Wikipedia cuidadosamente escolhida para ajudar na escrita do texto não me parece ser problemático.

O que deve-se observar é a *tag wiki* ser útil para o **nosso usuário**. Ela não deve substituir o artigo da Wikipedia ou ser um tratado geral sobre o assunto.

Então acho que usar trechos com parcimônia é uma boa, copiar sem contextualizar, não.

E claro que um link para o artigo na Wikipedia não só é desejável para o leitor achar mais detalhes (e é lá que eles devem estar) , mas também importante para identificar a fonte do trecho usado.

Provavelmente um caminho melhor é usar a *tag wiki* do SO, o que já impede colar integralmente sem adaptação já que está em inglês.