# Diretrizes para criação de tag wikis

Tags: debate, tags, proposta-para-faq, edição, wikis-de-tags

Ontem havia um grande volume de sugestões de edição em wikis de tags e excertos (ou "fragmentos", como foi traduzido). Acho isso excelente, esse tipo de conteúdo é importantíssimo e estava faltando no site. Porém, alguns wikis não me agradaram muito, e acabei rejeitando ou pulando vários deles durante meu processo de análise. Por exemplo, vi excertos que focavam na definição do termo e não mencionavam o uso da tag. Outras vezes, o excerto ou o próprio wiki não pareceram objetivos, utilizando uma linguagem quase de propaganda ([exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/387), [exemplo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/409)).

### Funções dos wikis

Para definirmos diretrizes sobre o formato dos wikis, primeiro é preciso determinar para que eles servem. Eu vejo duas funções principais:

#### 1. Orientar os usuários sobre o uso da tag, principalmente novatos

Na hora de preencher as tags de uma pergunta, o sistema apresenta os excertos de wiki enquanto sugere tags com autocompletar. Portanto esses textos precisam ser curtos e objetivos. Batendo o olho no texto, o usuário deve ser capaz de identificar se está usando a tag corretamente ou não. Em certos casos, o excerto pode até incluir frases como "use esta tag para A, B, C" e/ou "não use para X, Y, Z" – contanto que se mantenham breves.

#### 2. Evitar a postagem de perguntas duplicadas ou fora de escopo.

Os wikis completos devem fornecer informações gerais sobre uma linguagem ou tecnologia, de maneira que possam ser indicados como leitura a usuários que postam duplicatas de perguntas frequentes, usuários que buscam referências gerais que estejam listadas no wiki (documentação, tutoriais), ou usuários que estão perguntando algo que, embora ligado à tag, não esteja no [escopo do site](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/264/quais-assuntos-devem-fazer-parte-do-nosso-foco-on-topic).

### Cópia e tradução de conteúdo

[Não é proibido copiar conteúdo de outros lugares](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/136/wikis-de-tag-copiados-do-wikipedia) para usar nos wikis, contanto que:

- Copiar esteja de acordo com a licença desse conteúdo
- O texto copiado faça sentido como wiki (creio que na maioria dos casos seja preciso adaptar)

Uma boa fonte para quem deseja criar tags são os wikis do próprio Stack Overflow em inglês, que podem ser total ou parcialmente traduzidos. O site tem cinco anos de trabalho comunitário sobre esses wikis, o que garante um conteúdo de qualidade especialmente nas tags mais utilizadas.

> **Nota**: os pontos acima são simplesmente **a minha opinião** sobre o assunto. Discordâncias
> e complementos são extremamente bem-vindos. O objetivo desta pergunta é colocar este tema em discussão, para que, juntos, possamos criar um padrão para a edição dos wikis.

---

**Referências** <sup>(en)</sup>

- [Tag Folksonomy and Tag Synonyms](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/tag-folksonomy-and-tag-synonyms/)
- [Redesigned Tags Page](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/03/redesigned-tags-page/)

Comment: Muito pertinente. A maioria eram meus e eu fui percebendo que a qualidade não era das melhores. Me surpreende que tenham tantas tag wikis de baixa qualidade no SO original. Isso talvez demonstre que elas não funcionam como esperado, mas isso é outra discussão. Quando eu vi as páginas do blog citadas sobre o assunto (até antes dessa pergunta ser colocada), já mudei a minha postura, e estou preparando edições para melhorar o que já foi colocado. Até porque a má qualidade do original realmente não deveria justificar o mesmo aqui, só demorei para perceber. Eu não trouxe fontes diferentes do SO.

Comment: Eu não achei os seus ruins. Tem coisas que eu mexeria, mas são excelentes pontos de partida. Eu na verdade aprovei a maioria dos wikis que analisei, só rejeitei o que me pareceu inaceitável mesmo como ponto de partida. Impossível a primeira versão do wiki ser perfeita (ou mesmo a última, rs!). Precisamos valorizar o esforço de quem escreveu, e botar nosso esforço em cima para melhorar. Com o tempo cada tag vai criar uma comunidade que acaba mantendo o wiki. @bigown

Comment: Eu postei isto como uma espécie de faq-proposed. Precisamos ter orientações e discussões sobre o formato dos wikis em algum lugar, ou vai virar uma zona.

Comment: Tem coisas que eu queria fazer, mas achei que era cedo (precisam ter perguntas relevantes aqui), cortei coisas que poderiam ser legais mas agora não dá, mas deixei outras que talvez deveriam ter sido cortadas. Fui aprendendo com o processo. Tem algumas que eu fiz de madrugada, cansado e não ficaram tão boas quanto eu gostaria, mas vou melhorá-las. Todas foram traduzidas semi-manualmente do SO com adaptação livre em alguns casos. Muitas já está melhor aqui que no SO. E gosto das FAQ-proposed, útil p/ linkar em orientação p/ novatos.

Answer (score 6):

Essas diretrizes são ótimas e como o próprio bfavaretto citou, foram retiradas do blog do Stack Exchange e portando já são consagradas na rede.

## Fontes de informação

Eu trouxe textos para várias tags do Stack Overflow original traduzindo o texto que lá estavam. Ajudou e vai ajudar termos conteúdo relevante rápido e isso é bom para os buscadores nos achar.

Acho inclusive que sempre devemos **olhar o SO original quando for pegar um texto para a nossa wiki**. Muitas vezes o melhor começo é o que está lá, mesmo que não seja o ideal. E é comum estar longe do ideal. Me surpreendeu que muitos textos lá estão bem ruins e não seguem as diretrizes. É sintomático que até a tag que foi usada como exemplo no blog do que não deve ser feito, está exatamente com o problema apontado. Admito que alguns casos é complicado escrever algo relevante sem ser óbvio.

Há textos da tag wiki aqui foram criados (supostamente) de forma original. Ótimo, nenhum problema nisso, só que alguns casos o texto ficou bem fraco e no SO tinha algo bem melhor para começar. Temos que agradecer a boa vontade de vários usuários e estou aprovando quase todas edições, mas se o conteúdo original não for bom, pe melhor usar um fonte. Alguns conteúdos originais estão bem legais.

Faço um *mea culpa* de que alguns textos que eu trouxe do SO não estão muito bons também, parte porque surpreendentemente o texto lá está ruim, parte porque é difícil definir um texto legal, e parte porque traduzi mal, confiei o Google e não revisei o suficiente. Aos poucos vou melhorá-los. Todos podem fazer isso.

## Responsabilidade da comunidade específica

O mais importante que quero colocar é que essas edições não pode ficar nas mãos de poucos usuários. **Cada comunidade específica deve manter suas tags**. É estranho que a [php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) que é uma das mais usadas aqui é uma das piores entre as mais usadas e praticamente ninguém da enorme comunidade dela que temos aqui se empenhou em melhorá-la. As tags de maior sucesso são as que devem ter conteúdo melhor.

E alguns casos a definição de como a tag deve ser definida deve partir da necessidade específica dessa comunidade e pode ser diferente de outras tags. Ver mais em [Como tratar tags em árvore?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310/como-tratar-tags-em-arvore) onde cada comunidade deve escolher seu caminho.

## Melhor conteúdo dos fragmentos

Depois de analisar bastante e cometer vários erros, cheguei a conclusão que os **fragmentos devem indicar o uso correto da tag** e não qualquer definição do assunto. É óbvio, está na diretriz original, mas no SO isso não é seguido. Devemos evitar esse erro aqui.

A definição básica sobre o assunto e onde obter recursos, no site ou fora dele, devem ficar no texto principal. Claro que alguns casos a definição é fundamental para indicar o uso correto da tag. Neste caso a definição deve ajudar no uso da tag e não informar o que é o assunto. Se todos concordarem com isso, a maioria dos fragmentos estão errados (culpa minha).

O texto do fragmento geralmente está grande demais. Acho até que erraram ao dar tanto espaço. Se o fragmento não consegue ser mostrado por inteiro na página da tag, ele está maior do que deveria. Temos que melhorar isso.

## Recursos apontados

Enquanto não temos facilmente recursos em português para colocar nas wikis, **podemos ir colocando recursos em inglês** (indicando que a fonte está em inglês quando não é óbvio).

A minha **dúvida** é se devemos indicar para nossa FAQ da tag perguntas vindas do SO em inglês enquanto não temos as nossas perguntas para incluí-las. O que acham?

## Conclusão

Farei edições para colocar essas diretrizes em prática. Quem puder faça o mesmo.

Alguns pontos colocados vão um pouco contra o que se vê no SO original, mas acredito que vão de encontro à intenção original das diretrizes apresentadas no blog.

Alguém tem algo a complementar ou discordar? Precisamos da participação de todos para o site manter o rumo certo.

Comment: Ótimo. Eu não tive o seu fôlego para criar tags, mas tenho revisado várias – e admito que nem sempre sigo certas diretrizes que eu mesmo expus, como incluir instruções de uso no fragmento. Tenho privilegiado consertar o que posso rapidamente, e deixar outras melhorias para depois. Aliás, não vejo problemas se outros fizerem isso também, a tendência é que com o tempo os wikis fiquem mais precisos e completos. Especialmente quando comunidades forem se formando em torno das tags (acho que ainda está um pouco cedo para cobrar isso).

Comment: O que você vê de tão ruim no wiki sobre javascript? Claro que dá para melhorar, mas eu não acho ruim.

Comment: @bfavaretto Editei para deixar mais claro, porque na hora que estava escrevendo era outra :) E não está ruim, talvez tenha exagerado um pouco :) só acho que deveria ter mais edições para melhorá-la. Javascript já teve um interesse um pouco maior. Também não está nota 10, mas já houve interesse. Não pode é ficar 3 ou 4 pessoas fazendo tudo. E não é pela caraga, é pela falta de diversidade.

Comment: Sim, concordo. Mas você sabe que são as mesmas 3 ou 4 pessoas que virão ao meta ler isto neste momento, é um problema de ovo ou galinha. Espero que mais gente venha aqui participar das discussões.