# Como tratar tags em árvore?

Tags: debate, perguntas, proposta-para-faq, tags, big-7

Existem questões que usam tags para um produto ou tecnologia e para uma versão específica do mesmo.

Como devemos tratá-las? Uma diretriz única ou cada comunidade deve definir a sua? Em geral costuma-se usar a a tag geral e apenas a tag mais específica quando só funciona naquela versão.

Exemplos:

[visual-studio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio) e [visual-studio-2012](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2012)

[oracle](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle) e [oracle-11g](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle-11g) e ainda [oracle-11g-r2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle-11g-r2)

Tem casos específicos que merecem maior atenção:

[sqlite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlite) e [sqlite3](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlite3) Deveria ser `sqlite-3`? Ou pleo menos deveria ter esse sinônimo? Ou SQLite3 está sendo usado como nome do produto e não versão? Se é o nome do produto, faz sentido usar as duas tags juntas? Este caso não deveria ser sinônimo então? Lembrando que o [SQLite 4](http://sqlite.org/src4/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki) será um produto completamente diferente.

[laravel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel) e [laravel4](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel4) Caso semelhante, deve ser sinônimo? Deve usar apenas um? Faz sentido usar ambos sempre? Existem casos para usar um ou ambos? Laravel 4 é produto específico? Alguém usa outras versões? Sempre que se fala do Laravel, está se falando do 4? O que vai acontecer quando sair o Laravel 5?

Quais outras tags precisamos discutir sobre isso?

Devemos aplicar esta ou outras regras de marcação de perguntas ativamente sempre que encontrar algo errado mantendo a taxonomia da melhor forma possível?

Outro ponto relacionado: devemos ser o mais específico possível quando aplicar as tags? Quando é algo sobre um assunto específico da tecnologia, devemos sempre usar a tag desse assunto junto? Exemplo: [spring-mvc](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-mvc) trata do MVC especificamente aplicado ao Spring que tem semântica própria. É diferente de usar [spring](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring) e [mvc](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mvc).

Informações adicionais importantes sobre a criação da wiki que ajudará usar melhor a tag: [Diretrizes para criação de tag wikis](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300/diretrizes-para-criacao-de-tag-wikis)

Comment: Concordo plenamente. Se re-fizer a pergunta e incluir uma resposta voto nela. No SO(en) encontra-se grande misturada e por vezes os novos utilizadores usam tags super-específicas a pensar que estão a perguntar de uma maneira mais correcta e a pergunta cai no esquecimento porque ninguém a vê.

Comment: @Sergio está feito.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## Versões

Primeiro o mais óbvio: não usar tags para versões não estáveis, apenas para versões oficiais. Versões beta, release candidate, development, etc são muito localizadas.

Outro ponto é sempre ter a tag principal do produto ou tecnologia, nos exemplo acima [visual-studio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio) e [oracle](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle).

Tags de versões específicas só devem ser usadas quando a pergunta realmente está limitada àquela versão e neste caso deve ser o mais específico possível. Exemplificando, se a pergunta se encaixa:

- para qualquer versão do Oracle, use só [oracle](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle)
- especificamente para a versão 11g, use **também** [oracle-11g](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle-11g)
- no release 11g-r2 e nenhum outro release do 11g, use [oracle-11g-r2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle-11g-r2) mas **não** use [oracle-11g](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle-11g)

Ou seja, neste caso só pode ter uma tag de versão específica em cada tag.

## Múltiplas versões

Por outro lado, digamos que a pergunta se refere a mais de uma versão no mesmo nível, mas não todas. Exemplificando:

- para qualquer versão do Visual Studio, use só [visual-studio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio)
- se é específica para o 2012 e o 2013, use **ambas** [visual-studio-2012](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2012) e [visual-studio-2013](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2013)

Ver: [Como fazer um Ajuda equivalente ao Microsoft Help Viewer, mas no Visual Studio 2012/2013?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/415/como-fazer-um-ajuda-equivalente-ao-microsoft-help-viewer-mas-no-visual-studio-2)

## SQLite

A tag SQLite é uma bagunça no SO. Tem pergunta só [sqlite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlite) e é específica para a versão 3, tem só [sqlite3](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlite3) mesmo não sendo específica e claro tem com duas tags nas duas situações. Por isso fico perdido. Não sou um grande especialista em SQLite mas vejo SQLite e SQLite3 como sinônimos. E acho fácil discordar disso também :)

## Laravel

Vou deixar para a comunidade do Laravel falar sobre a tag deles.

## Uso de tags de assuntos específicos

Acho que devemos ser sempre o mais específico possível. Usar a tag da tecnologia, da versão quando for específica e **também** a tag do assunto específico. E a tag do assunto deve conter o nome da tecnologia quando puder ter ambiguidade.

Answer (score 7):

As tags sejam do "Laravel", "SQLite", sejam de qualquer outra linguagem tem que seguir a mesma filosofia de criação, utilização e gestão, caso contrário vamos ter que publicar um livro intitulado "*Como utilizar StackOverflow em Português*"!

Eu concordo com a resposta dado pelo @bigown, mas como ficaram dois assuntos específicos em aberto que na minha opinião não deveria ter "tratamento" especial, vou completar a resposta dele:

<sup>(ia deixar comentário, mas era um bocadinho grande)</sup>

## Laravel

No caso particular do "Laravel", pelo que vejo, a documentação está separada com acessos diferentes para a versão pretendida e com escolha da sub-versão:

- [Documentação Laravel 3](http://three.laravel.com/docs)
- [Documentação Laravel 4.0 e 4.1](http://laravel.com/docs)

  Na mesma página, mas temos que escolher no menu superior.

Faz todo o sentido existirem tags para cada versão pois a própria separação da documentação indica-nos que as coisas são diferentes de versão para versão e como em qualquer outra linguagem ou framework, as coisas mudam:

**Exemplo:**

```
Um determinado assunto problemático na versão 4.0 não se consegue reproduzir na versão 3.0
porque não existe a funcionalidade causadora do problema.
```

## SQLite

As tags SQLite e SQLite3 estão mal construidas e são mal utilizadas no SO original:

- Minha ideia:

  A ideia que sempre tive e que sempre vi aplicada e discutida no METÃO e que cada tag tem um significado especifico que ajuda a identificar corretamente o conteúdo da pergunta, pelo que a minha leitura das tags de SQLite é:

  [sqlite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlite) -> Deve ser utilizador quando o problema é comum a qualquer versão da linguagem.

  [sqlite-3](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlite-3) -> Deve ser utilizado quando o problema é especifico à versão 3.0 ou sub-versões 3.x.
- **Estão bem porque:**

  Estão bem porque existe uma tag para cobrir todas as versões e uma tag para cobrir uma versão especifica.
- **Estão mal porque:**

  Estão mal porque devido à falta de informação na wiki de tag, e também porque existem tags como meu-nome-3 e meu-nome3 e meunome3, estas e muitas outras são mal utilizadas.

  [**Caso prático**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4373562/352449) onde um utilizador colocou uma pergunta sobre uma diferença entre SQLite e SQLite3:

  Aqui o utilizador usou a tag [sqlite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlite) para identificar esta pergunta. Repare-se também que a pergunta data a *7 Dezembro 2010*.

  Mas depois a pergunta foi editada e adicionaram as tags [sqlite3](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlite3) [sqlite2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sqlite2) em *29 Março 2011*.

  Ou seja, no meu ver, começou mal por não identificar que estava a falar especificamente da SQLite 2 e SQLite 3, mas depois de editado continua mal porque ficou com a tag SQLite (tag genérica), e com as especificas referentes às versões em causa.

---

## Conclusão

Se vamos ter um determinado método para gerir tags, esse método tem que ser aplicado a **TODAS** as tags, caso contrário ninguém se vai entender.

Deverá existir uma tag para a linguagem e uma tag para cada versão da linguagem, de forma a que o conteúdo possa ser bem identificado e as respostas sejam em conformidade com a versão da linguagem em uso onde o problema pode ser reproduzido.

De igual forma, deverão existir tags complementares que se referem à ação em particular para identificar de forma clara o problema.

**Exemplo:**

Exemplo de um problema que o utilizador está a ter com um `statment` de `PDO` na versão 5.4 do PHP:

[php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) [php-5.4](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php-5.4) [pdo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pdo) [pdo-statment](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pdo-statment)

- Utilizador a responder

  Para ajudar e responder, sei que tenho que ter em conta o funcionamento do PHP 5.4, com PDO de forma a garantir que a solução para a questão relativa ao statment vai funcionar para o utilizador que colocou a pergunta.
- Indexação e Pesquisa

  De forma a que a pergunta seja localizada e indexada em condições, pode ser aplicada também a tag da linguagem "base", neste caso a [php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php). Muito embora a mesma não seja prioritária no caso de estarmos a atingir o limite das 5 tags que cada pergunta pode conter e ainda tivermos necessidade de especificar algo mais.

**Nota:** Para o caso das frameworks, cada uma tem a sua linguagem base com requerimentos mínimos, pelo que, é como que implícito que se estou a usar a framework X a solução depende dessa framework a correr na versão x.xx da linguagem de programação Y. Salvo cenários específicos em que a framework pode correr em mais que uma versão da linguagem base é que devemos aplicar as tags para a linguagem base:

[laravel-4](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel-4) não precisaria da tag [php-5.3.7], bastava a tag [php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) se não ultrapassasse o limite das 5 tags na pergunta.

### Tag Wiki

O resumo de cada tag deve identificar corretamente a utilização da mesma para que o utilizador saiba em que situações deve aplicar a mesma.

### Revisão

Quem tem interesse em editar perguntas de forma a melhorar as mesmas deve também avaliar e confirmar que as tags em uso estão corretas e são de facto as melhores para identificar o conteúdo e problema em questão.

---

## Discussão

Devemos discutir a forma como vai ficar a gestão das tags, mas sou da opinião que devemos evitar a todo o custo os "casos específicos", pois, para além de achar que não existem (são criados no "calor" do momento), se vamos abrir regras particulares para linguagem X, amanhã já temos regras para a linguagem Y e no futuro estamos tal e qual como o SO original... sem uma linha de referência coerente para o uso das tags.

<sup>Depois de ler o texto da resposta, achei melhor voltar a indicar aqui o que disse no topo: *Eu concordo com a resposta dado pelo @bigown* e com a forma como o mesmo sugere para a estrutura das tags. Só quis deixar claro porque é que sou contra exceções.</sup>

Comment: Excelente! Era esse tipo de informação adicional que gostaria de ver aqui.

Comment: Sobre o exemplo dado, não seria melhor incluir a tag genérica `php` também?

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal Nesse campo as opiniões divergem! A minha opinião é que se tens a tag PHP5, a tag PHP não vai trazer nada de novo. Mas pode existir um motivo pela qual a inclusão dessa tag traga mais valias, eu só não vejo com clareza essas mais valias! Falam na indexação de motores de busca, ou resultados de pesquisa no próprio site... PHP deveria dar resultados referentes a PHP acrescidos de resultados referentes a PHPx... não sei se é assim que funciona! Caso não já seria bom adicionar a tag PHP. **Nota:** O exemplo pode também não ser muito "famoso" :)

Comment: Não sei o quanto o google seria mais esperto (certamente um pouco), mas o mecanismo de busca do site não traria resultados com php5 se a busca for por php, a menos que essas tags fossem sinônimas (e php não poderia ser sinônimo de php4 e php5 ao mesmo tempo). Aliás, php5 talvez não seja suficiente no caso do PHP, já que há diferenças grandes no php 5.4 e 5.5 em relação às versões anterior. É confusa essa questão das versões, ainda não estou seguro que exista uma solução ideal.

Comment: Um exemplo para pensarmos: o Laravel 4 requer PHP 5.3.7+. Se qualquer pergunta sobre esse framework precisar ter as tags php, php5, laravel e laravel4, só sobra uma tag para deixar a pergunta mais específica. Parece ruim, não? A solução mais limpa seria usar somente php e laravel como tags. Só perguntas sobre a versão anterior usariam laravel3. Problema: quando sair o Laravel 5, as perguntas já existentes precisariam ser reclassificadas como laravel4.

Comment: @bfavaretto Alterei um pouco o exemplo com base nos comentários, de forma a clarificar um pouco mais o meu ponto de vista. (Mas estou aberto a mais criticas e/ou sugestões).

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal Alterei um pouco o exemplo com base nos comentários, de forma a clarificar um pouco mais uma possível maneira de lidar com essa questão. Tive em conta os problemas levantados pelo bfavaretto.

Comment: Não haverá solução ideal. Só me importo que haja um padrão. Vejo a preferência do pessoal colocar todos as tags possíveis, mas pessoalmente prefiro que não haja redundância. Acho que a questão principal é usar ou não a tag mais genérica quando a mais específica foi usada. Temos que pensar também que não adianta muito determinar um padrão, mas quase ninguém gostar de usá-lo, portanto não será usado. Alguns exemplos são os ideais, mas não parecem fáceis de usar. Claro que os usuários principais acaberão sendo responsáveis por fazer a taxonomia correta.

Comment: Não precisamos seguir o SO, mas lá o PHP é sinônimo do PHP-5, para citar um exemplo. Concordo com o @bfavaretto que isso pode ser um problema quando surgir o PHP 6. Lá a versões menores tem tags específicas, mas o 4 não tem as menores. Isso reflete a maneira como o produto foi lançado e fez sucesso. Vamos seguir o padrão de cada produto ou um padrão único? Fazer mudar o padrão no meio do caminho quando o produto mudar o padrão? Vamos tentar fazer futurologia?

Answer (score 7):

Minha posição talvez seja simplista, gostaria de saber se acham simples demais. Parte de dois princípios:

1. **Sempre incluir tag da linguagem**
   Isso fará com que o *syntax highlight* seja automaticamente aplicado em blocos de código (hoje não está funcionando automaticamente, mas considero isso um [bug](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/66/o-syntax-highlight-ainda-nao-funciona-para-varias-linguagens)).
2. **Só incluir tag específica de versão (de linguagem ou framework) para problemas com uma versão específica**, especialmente se for uma versão anterior ou muito recente. Ou seja, **a tag limpa, sem número de versão, ficaria para a versão atual no momento da postagem** – e, claro, para os casos em que a versão não é relevante.

Por exemplo, as perguntas sobre *Laravel* eu classificaria como [php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) [laravel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel). Perguntas específicas do Laravel 3 ganhariam [laravel-3](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel-3) em vez de [laravel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel). Se a versão 4.1, quando lançada, for substancialmente diferente da 4, a comunidade reclassifica as perguntas antigas como [laravel-4](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel-4), e a tag [laravel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel) passa a ser utilizada para a versão atual.

Sei que exige um esforço de reclassificação de tempos em tempos, mas é algo que as comunidades em torno de cada tag conseguem resolver com relativa facilidade (ocorre com frequência no SO), se necessário com ajuda de moderadores ou até dos desenvolvedores.

Comment: Acho que o ponto 2 já há consenso se for usar sempre a tag da linguagem. Não? A dúvida maior é justamente essa. O ponto 1 é um argumento interessante em favor de usá-la. Não estou fechando questão nisso. Se esse padrão for usado, ele provavelmente terá que ser usado também quando uma tecnologia pressupõe uma linguagem, nesse caso funcionaria de forma análoga à versão. Não gosto muito da solução que exige *retag* quando surgir uma versão nova.

Comment: O retag seria consequência do ponto 2, não? A menos que tenhamos uma regra para versões de linguagem, e outra para versões de frameworks e libs.

Comment: Acho que não, se entendi certo o ponto 2. Se a pergunta é específica para uma versão, nunca vai precisar de *retag* em massa. Essa operação só seria necessária se usar, por exemplo, `laravel` como sinônimo de `laravel 4`. Se `laravel 4` for usada apenas para indicar que a pergunta é específica, não precisaria de *retag*. Se você está falando do problema da árvore, ou seja, 4 deveria ser usado p/ qualquer 4. Aí teríamos que pensar no 4.0, 4.1, etc., já que o 4.0 é um *minor* da *major*, neste caso, 4 é diferente de 4.0. Aí o *retag* de 4 p/ 4.0 **talvez** seja aceitável. Mas ainda **não gosto**

Comment: Acho que não me expressei bem, @bigown. Idealmente, gostaria que as perguntas sobre laravel 4 estivessem classificadas como `laravel`, sem versão. As tags com versão seriam usadas somente para versões antigas, ou cutting-edge. Acho limpo, e acredito que seja assim que muitas pessoas pensam na hora de perguntar ("como fazer X no laravel"). Sobre a necessidade de tags para versões minor, acho que depende do caso.

Comment: Editei para deixar isso mais explícito, @bigown.

Comment: Então agora o ponto 2 não é tão consenso assim :) Não digo que não seja a solução que devemos seguir, mas não gosto dela, por forçar *retag*, ser esquisito e contextual.

Comment: Eu entendo as discordâncias, @bigown. Estou procurando uma solução que seja limpa e descomplicada, mas ainda não achei; nem sei se há.

Answer (score 5):

## Laravel

O Laravel é um framework php que segue práticas modernas de orientação a objetos, e isso nos dá alguns pontos interessantes para refletir:

1) É possível instalar em um projeto, apenas um componente do Laravel, por exemplo, Blade, é o sistema de templates, Eloquent é o pacote responsável pelos models e banco de dados, dentre outros.

2) As Diferentes versões do Framework trazem significativas mudanças, e nem sempre um solução a um problema na versão 3 irá ajudar um problema semelhante na versão 4, e um problema que acontece na versão 4 talvez não exista na versão 4.1.

Eu criei a versão inicial da Wiki da tag aqui no SO quando ainda não discutíamos tais diretrizes, foi sugerido na época, mantermos o padrão das tags:
[php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) [laravel4](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel4) [componente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/componente)

Isso nos daria flexibilidade de identificar facilmente a versão do framework com a tag Laravel4, o componente em questão e também conseguir ajuda de toda a comunidade PHP com a tag [php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php)

Porém, isso não atrelaria diferentes versões do Laravel na mesma tag, proponho que sigamos o seguinte padrão:
[php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) [laravel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel) [laravel-4](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel-4) [quando conhecido/aplicável: [laravel-componente](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel-componente) ]

isso daria flexibilidade e um bom ponto de partida para quem for responder.

Comment: O máximo de tags permitidas numa pergunta é 5. Se alguém precisar usar mais que duas para especificar o problema, qual das 3 básicas você cortaria?

Comment: não é uma lei, podemos deixar que a pessoa remova as 5 tags e adicione as que forem necessárias, e a comunidade edita o que for pertinente a padronização, a tag laravel sem versão é uma ideia para conseguirmos listar todas as perguntas do framework, independente da versão, mas não oferece dados adicionais ao problema.
Acho que podemos corta-la se for o caso, ou mesmo instruir adicionar somente Laravel e a Comunidade tenta adequar com a edição

Comment: Por outro lado a Tag PHP está intrínseca numa questão sobre Laravel