# Existem tags implícitas?

Tags: debate, proposta-para-faq, tags, big-7

Estamos discutindo em [Como tratar tags em árvore?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310/como-tratar-tags-em-arvore) algumas coisas que podem indicar que certas tags são implícitas ([php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) estaria implícito quando se usa [laravel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel)).

Agora a pergunta [Como evitar uma IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has changed but ListView did not receive a notification?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1945/como-evitar-neste-caso-uma-illegalstateexception-the-content-of-the-adapter-has) usa [android](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) e deixa implícito que é sobre [java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java). Java é a principal mas não a única linguagem para se programar um dispositivo Android.

Como devemos tratar essas situações e outras semelhantes que surjam?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A base é saber se alguém que tenha conhecimento de apenas uma das tags pode resolver a questão. Muitas vezes em uma pergunta sobre algum problema com uma biblioteca é na verdade algo que pode ser resolvido por uso de algo da linguagem em si e nada tem haver com a biblioteca, ou com o acrescimo de outra dependência. Quando na questão essa possibilidade existe, acredito que a tag geral da linguagem deve estar presente. No entanto se a questão for explicitamente sobre uma API ou sobre como lidar com o comportamento de uma biblioteca, algo que alguém sem conhecer ela não poderia responder, a tag da linguagem não é tão necessária.

A [questão que você citou](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1945/como-evitar-neste-caso-uma-illegalstateexception-the-content-of-the-adapter-has) está claramente presa à API e duvido muito que seja um problema com o código Java, e sim no uso das classes do Android. Não precisaria por a tag Java nesse caso, embora ajude a dar mais visibilidade (não seria errado por).

No entanto é algo que não podemos generalizar. Muitas vezes o autor da pergunta não faz ideia de que tipo de resposta ele espera. Se houver dúvida é melhor por a tag da linguagem.

Comment: Concordo totalmente. Na dúvida, uma boa orientação seria incluir a tag da linguagem. No mínimo daria mais visibilidade, como você disse.

Comment: O autor da pergunta errar a tag é normal, a dúvida é justamente se devemos editar para melhorá-la, para deixar mais claro do que se trata e dar mais visibilidade (desde que de forma adequada e não forçada)

Comment: @bigown Vi que você acabou de incluir a tag ruby numa pergunta que eu editei e deixei a tag de fora aguardando mais opiniões aqui. Pensei se eu não deveria deixar esse tipo de edição para quando a pergunta tiver ficado estacionada, sem respostas, por um tempo (indicando pouca visibilidade). Mas agora, pensando melhor, mal não faz, então acho bom colocar a tag como você fez.

Comment: @bfavaretto É que ali eu achei claramente que era sobre Ruby. Não considerei que fosse o mesmo caso que uma tag deixa outra implícita. Se acha que eu errei nessa avaliação (ou qualquer outra, gosto de tratar aqui de casos específicos que possam ser usados para generalizar ações), pode reverter, não me oporei. Não reverterei porque ainda penso da mesma forma.

Comment: @bigown Eu entendi que a pergunta era sobre como criar um teste específico com o rspec, não sobre um aspecto particular da linguagem. Mas não vou reverter, eu tenderia mesmo a incluir a tag como você fez, e nesse caso me contive pensando em esperar esta discussão caminhar mais. Pessoalmente, acho mesmo que a tag de linguagem deve constar na maior parte das perguntas, como eu [disse](http://meta.br.stackoverflow.com/questions/310/como-tratar-tags-em-arvore/464#464) em outra discussão sobre o assunto.

Comment: No caso da pergunta inicialmente citada eu discordo da tag `Java` por se tratar de um problema relacionado À API do Android como já foi mencionado e também porque usuários monitorando a tag `Java` podem não ter interesse em questões de `Android`.