# A tag java8 deveria ser java-8

Tags: suporte, status-pronto, tag-específica

Conforme os [nossos padrões de versionamento](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/310/215), a tag [java8](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java8) deveria ser [java-8](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-8), certo? Há poucas perguntas nessa tag, então pode-se fazer isso mesmo manualmente (num momento apropriado), mas se algum moderador tiver ferramentas melhores pra isso, tanto melhor.

Lista de perguntas com a tag [java8](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java8):

- [Colecção Map<k,v> Metodos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/29961/colec%c3%a7%c3%a3o-mapk-v-metodos)
- [Desenvolvimento de jogos para celulares](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/29234/desenvolvimento-de-jogos-para-celulares)
- [JPA com a API Date do Java 8](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/25398/jpa-com-a-api-date-do-java-8)
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/22767/problemas-com-el3-no-tomcat-8-n%c3%a3o-consigo-usar-os-novos-recursos-da-el3-no-jsp
- [O que são interfaces funcionais?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11162/interfaces-funcionais-em-java)
- [Como funciona o Spliterator no Java 8?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/441/como-funciona-o-spliterator-no-java-8)

(não verifiquei se em todas elas a tag é apropriada; quem for fazer a mudança, favor fazer isso)

Além disso, creio que essa pergunta também poderia receber essa tag - já que se trata de uma característica nova dessa versão. Concordam?

[Quais as vantagens das Expressões Lambda presentes no Java 8?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/269/quais-as-vantagens-das-express%C3%B5es-lambda-presentes-no-java-8)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sem dúvida. Está feito, a nova tag foi criada e as perguntas de [java8](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java8) foram migradas para [java-8](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-8).