# Tag 'java10' deveria ser chamada 'java-10'

Tags: suporte, tag-específica

A tag `java10`<sup>1</sup> deveria ser `java-10` para seguir o padrão das outras tags `java-8` e `java-9`.

Essa mudança foi efetuada com a tag `java8`, ver esse [artigo](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1860/85830) e também no site inglês.

Eventualmente criar um sinônimo `java10`.

*<sup>1 [artigos usando java10](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java10)</sup>*

Comment: Concordo plenamente, mas não consigo fazê-lo do celular

Answer (score 7):

Feito!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!