# Tags de versões específicas devem ser sinônimos de sua tag "mãe"?

Tags: debate, tags

Existem várias de tags de versões específicas de produtos, tomemos como exemplo a tag [java-8](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-8).

Deveria esta tag ser um sinônimo da tag [java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java)?

Comment: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310/como-tratar-tags-em-%C3%A1rvore?rq=1 dup?

Comment: Yup[.](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/74/bfavaretto)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não acho. Existem situações mais que suficientes em que você pode querer algo que é específico de uma versão da linguagem de programação, como querer saber detalhes da implementação de expressões lambda em Java, que só existem a partir de Java 8.

Da mesma maneira, saber se você está desenvolvendo algo em Python 3 ajuda na hora de decidir como responder sua pergunta sobre manipulação de strings ou texto, por exemplo. E por aí vai...

Como eu disse, são várias as situações em que a distinção entre da versão é benéfica para quem responde (e para a organização do site), ao passo em que a sinonimização não produz nenhum benefício concreto.

Comment: @jbueno 