# É certo termos tags específicas para as versões do Java?

Tags: debate, tag-específica

O Java 9 (release previsto para setembro próximo) trará consigo uma série de novidades, inclusive a tão falada *modularização*.

Essa, por si só, afeta **muito** o desenvolvimento desde a criação da primeira classe.

---

Temos uma tag específica para o [Java 8](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/java-8/info).

A dúvida é: **está certo termos uma tag específica para o Java 8?** Se sim, **devemos criar uma tag específica para o Java 9 também?**

Vale lembrar que existe a (grande) possibilidade de colocarem apenas as tags Java 8 ou 9 (ou 10, 11, 12 e por aí vai) nas perguntas por problemas não específicos da versão.
Isso acontece repetidas vezes com a tag [JSF 2.2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf-2.2/info), por exemplo.

Comment: As tags especificas devem existir em perguntas específicas, se colocarem uma dessas em um problema não específica de uma versão deve-se editar e deixar somente a tag geral. A tag java-9 poderá ser criada sem problemas quando surgir a primeira pergunta dessa tag.

Comment: Relacionado: [Como tratar tags em árvore?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/310/3117)

Comment: @Math legal! Não tinha encontrado essa pergunta. Então devemos sempre colocar as tags principais (Java, por exemplo) na pergunta mesmo se já tiver a tag da versão?

Comment: Teoricamente sim, pelo menos isso que a foi dito no outro tópico e a maioria parece concordar, se estão fazendo isso na prática ou não daí já não sei dizer, mas seria legal ter um padrão.

Comment: @Math ok. Isso já responde à pergunta. Como posso fecha-la?

Comment: Pode ser assim? Pois afinal acabei não acrescentando nada do que já tinha no outro tópico

Comment: @Math claro! Valeu!