# Tags de versões de linguagem

Tags: debate

Não sei se isso aqui é duplicado. Mas, existem várias tags como [php-5](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php-5), [php-7](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php-7), [php-7.1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php-7.1), assim como em outras linguagens, o [python-3.x](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x), [python-2.7](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-2.7) ou até o [delphi-10](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delphi-10). Deve ter várias outras, mas acho que isso suficiente como exemplo.

---

Se existe "Linguagem-1.0", porque deveria utilizar a tag de "Linguagem", qual o sentido do [php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) ou do [python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python)? Se for para "englobar qualquer versão" porque usar "Python-2.7" não faz automaticamente ser parte de "Python"?

Estava procurando por uma pergunta, quando pesquisei usando o filtro de  `[python]` não encontrei. Então pesquisei pelo que me recordava da pergunta e achei, daí notei a diferença das tags, ela possuía `[python-3.x]` ao invés de `[python]`. Acabei até por descobrir que funciona usar `"[python*]"`, mas isso também busca por outras tags, sem ser somente de versões diferentes. Além disso não há como definir `[python*]` como uma "Tag Favorita", ou tem?!

---

Não sei se isso é possível de ser feito. Na minha opinião as tags contendo as versões (ex. `PHP-5`) deveriam ser filhas da tag da linguagem o (ex. `PHP`). Isso até permitiria apenas usar `PHP-5` e já iria fazer parte da tag da linguagem. Isso ainda tornaria mais fácil responder, porque saberíamos os recursos disponíveis naquela versão e ainda mais fácil de achar, porque tudo estaria dentro de "PHP" e poderia ser buscado individualmente como `PHP-5`.

Vejo também que algumas linguagens, PHP é uma delas, que tem poucas perguntas usando as tags de versões, enquanto outras possuem maior número de perguntas usando.

Comment: Relacionada: [Como tratar tags em árvore?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/310/66203)

Answer (score 7):

Porque existem especificidades em cada versão. Python 2.7 e 3.0 são incompatíveis. Eventualmente algum problema só faz sentido se for Python 3.3. Então tem a *tag* geral pra dizer a linguagem e a versão quando for pertinente.

Não faz sentido colocar a *tag* de versão da linguagem se a versão não for importante.

O pessoal usa muito errado? Sim, usa. Este é outro problema e podemos arrumar.

Acho que o resto foi discutido em [Como tratar tags em árvore?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/310/101).

Comment: De pleno acordo.

Comment: E se for somente utilizado a tag com a versão, faria sentido adicionar a tag da linguagem apenas ou isso seria redundante? Por exemplo, se a pergunta possui a tag `python-2.7`, faria sentido adicionar `python` também?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss faz sim para ajudar quem segue os feeds de tags maiores como [python], afinal feeds (rss/atom/etc) pode ter ficado meio esquecido mas é muito util. Existem outras maneiras de seguir certas tags e creio que quem segue uma tag `[python]` por exemplo não gostaria de perder uma postagem interessante que só ficou na tag `[python-2.7]`. PS: Fora os feeds, o proprio site tem um sistema de destaque configurável, veja um exemplo: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQjE9.png

Answer (score 3):

Eu não entendi o intuito da postagem, o que presumi foi:

### 1. Sugestão de ferramenta para editar postagens com tags

Você esta sugerindo uma mudança no sistema que faça com que ele tenha tags "filhas" ou algum sistema de edição em massa para adicionar tags [php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php) as perguntas que tenham [php-5](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php-5)

Se isto for uma pergunta logo vou adiantando que **até aonde eu entendo** do sistema, isto é algo que não existe, nem mesmo no SOen, você pode sugerir no [***Metão***](https://meta.stackexchange.com), talvez lá ganhe visibilidade, já que seria(m) ferramenta(s) para todos sites.

### 2. Como atuar com as tags cujo existam tags "filhas"

Se isto for uma sugestão de como nós usuários devemos atuar com as tags, pessoalmente penso que sempre devemos adicionar as tags relevantes para a pergunta, por exemplo se for uma pergunta de Python e estou usando Python 3.6 e a pergunta é sobre compatibilidade de um script para rodar no 3.5 (é só exemplo existem muitas outras situações) então além da tag [python-3.5](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.5) também deverá sempre conter [python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), o motivo disto são as pessoas que seguem as tags através de:

- Feeds (rss, atom), se olhar no rodapé de quase todas as páginas do site tem um feed customizado para "seguir" tags, perguntas e algumas coisas a mais, exemplo na tag Python:

  > [image: feed]

  Pra quem não sabe o que são Feeds (ou Web Feed): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_feed
- Realce na página inicial e páginas de busca:

  [image: realce]

  Se o autor da pergunta não tivesse adicionado a tag [python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) na pergunta eu não teria notado ela no destaque.

Comment: Na verdade é os dois casos. Então deveria editar perguntas que contem "Python-3x" e não contêm "Python"? Sempre que incluir "XX-1.1" teria que incluir "XX"? A "sugestão" seria uma forma de automatizar isso, se este fosse o uso esperado. Por exemplo [1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/238879/erro-ao-ler-arquivo-csv-no-pandas), [2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/238865/aplicando-mascara-em-uma-matriz), [3](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/238831/adicionar-0-depois-da-v%C3%ADrgula) não incluem "Python", apenas o "Python-X.X", acho isso estranho.

Comment: @Inkeliz então eu já respondi, não existe ferramenta que automatize, talvez moderadores ou CMs tenham, mas nós mortais não temos isto e se isto existir só abrindo uma solicitação tag por tag, ainda sim seria bem burocrático (supondo que exista), o melhor que podemos fazer é simplesmente nós mesmo editarmos. Como digo as vezes: *é o que tem pra hoje :)*