# Destaque sintático para a tag Java 8?

Tags: novo-recurso, syntax-highlighting

Fiz uma pergunta usando a tag [java-8](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-8), pois era para resolver especificamente naquela versão do Java. Eu esperava que o *syntax-highlighting* do [java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) fosse aplicado automaticamente, mas não foi o caso.

Eu sei que poderia colocar o `<!-- language-all: lang-java -->`, mas seria mais conveniente se o *syntax-highlighting* fosse automático.

Imagem da [versão original](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/286810/1), sem ênfase sintática:

<kbd>[image: código Java sem ênfase sintática]</kbd>

Imagem da [versão com ênfase sintática](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/286810/2):

<kbd>[image: código Java com ênfase sintática]</kbd>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vou oferecer uma solução melhor. Coloque a [java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) na pergunta e tudo está resolvido, até porque é o mais correto para colocar a perguntas aos olhos da comunidade de Java que provavelmente assina a *tag* geral, mas tem pouca chance de assinar a *tag* de versão específica.

Portanto considero isto prejudicial para a classificação do conteúdo do site, incentivará não colocar a *tag* adequada.

Se houver discordância dessa posição é possível que a gente faça.

Comment: Então isso é um sinal que tive um entendimento ruim então das leituras que fiz (ok, faz um bom tempo) das questões [Tags de versões de linguagem](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/6358/64969) e [Como tratar tags em árvore?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/310/64969)

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado sim, pode até ter sido culpa minha não ter sido claro, mas dei uma relida e achei que está claro que é assim que deveria ser :)

Comment: Eu reli e vi inclusive que tem ênfase "especificamente para a versão 11g, use **também** oracle-11g" xD Eu que não soube ler