# Devo repetir o fragmento no corpo da wiki de tag?

Tags: debate, wikis-de-tags, conteúdo

Vejo em muitas edições que o fragmento introduz a tag, e o corpo do wiki **continua** a partir daí, de modo que olhando para a edição isoladamente ela parece fora de contexto e partindo de um ponto arbitrário. Mas o corpo não me parece uma continuação do fragmento, aliás quando se abre o "Saiba mais" o fragmento nem é exibido por padrão (a menos que o usuário clique em "mostrar fragmento" na parte de baixo). Em geral rejeito essas edições, a menos que sinta que muita coisa boa vai se perder.

De minha parte, sempre repito o conteúdo do fragmento no corpo da wiki. Não copio e colo, simplesmente "distribuo" o que está sendo dito no fragmento por todo o texto - uma vez que não há a restrição da brevidade, então posso me expressar melhor e/ou elaborar mais cada ponto. Isso está correto, ou devo omitir do corpo da wiki aquilo que já foi mencionado no fragmento?

Answer (score 5):

Pessoalmente faço com descreveste, ou seja:

**Fragmento**

No fragmento coloco uma breve descrição e sempre que possível uma indicação de quando é que a mesma deve ser utilizada.

Dado que este texto é o que aparece quando paramos o rato sobre a tag, faz sentido descrever a mesma, mas também ajudar a clarificar quando é que deve ser utilizada.

**Descrição**

Já na descrição da tag, o texto que utilizei no fragmento aplico como o primeiro paragrafo, mas de uma forma mais elaborada.

Este paragrafo ajuda a clarificar o texto abreviado que consta do fragmento e ajuda a servir de introdução à completa descrição que se segue.

Answer (score 1):

**Eu tenho adotado um ou outro seletivamente**. No corpo eu costumo usar a formatação como diferencial.

Na verdade eu tenho tentando seguir o que está no SO na maioria dos casos. Que por sinal nem sempre está bom (o que me impressionou, já disse aqui: [Diretrizes para criação de tag wikis](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300/diretrizes-para-criacao-de-tag-wikis))

**Se for idêntico eu tento evitar**. Mas alguns casos fica complicado.

Tenho tentado colocar no fragmento uma informação de como usar a tag, mesmo isso não estando presente no orignal do SO.

Recusei um ou outro fragmento que **mal tinha uma frase completa**, principalmente nos casos de ter **texto melhor no SO original**.

Mas não sei bem se é o melhor para quem está lendo. Alguém mais acha redundante e desnecessário na maioria dos casos?

Não tenho adotado um padrão único justamente por ter dúvidas sobre qual é melhor, mas seria bom ter um.

Tenho trazido muitas wikis de tag para cá mas não vou fazer isso eternamente e nem vou melhorar todas. Parte deverá ser das comunidades específicas. Quando o site for graduado, provavelmente vou adotar algumas para administrar mais de perto e ir olhando algumas outras.

Algumas que pretendo trabalhar bem e já podem ser usadas um pouco como modelo inicial (ainda não está bom): [c](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c), [c++](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) e [c#](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23).

Muita coisa precisa ser melhorada. Os textos deveriam servir como FAQs para o tema. Mas ainda não temos questões ideais para isso e espero que ninguém coloque qualquer questão tola como se fosse útil para a FAQ.

Ainda vamos ter que falar muito sobre tag wikis, por isso estou aproveitando o espaço. Semana que vem vou abrir várias questões sobre o tema.

---

<sub>Dica: Tem um motivo de eu deixar algumas tags aparentemente importantes sem edição :P Eu acho que algumas precisam ser debatidas, entre outros pontos, se devem ser proibidas.</sub>

Comment: Não acho nada redundante, à limites para o que se consegue dizer no fragmento, além que o fragmento é mesmo isso: uma ou duas linhas máximo! Já vi fragmentos que quase adormeço a ler o texto todo e revela-se pouco útil porque não tenho indicações práticas relativas à utilização da tag. O fragmento mais elaborado como introdução à descrição da tag (1 paragrafo) parece-me ser o melhor que tenho visto e feito.

Comment: @Zuul Claro que se há diferença, eu tenho deixado. Quando é idêntico, nem mesmo tem formação melhor no corpo, eu tenho evitado duplicar, mas até acho que pode ser melhor copiar também. Bom você tocar na questão no tamanho. Também estava achando um pouco grande (tem muitos assim no SO) mas por outro lado não queria que ninguém achasse que estava tentando ganhar +2 por quase nada :) Espero que todos vão colocando dicas assim para que eu (e qualquer outro interessado) vá aperfeiçoando.