# Aprovação de tags wikis sem qualidade

Tags: debate, comportamento, wikis-de-tags

Algumas pessoas estão tentando colaborar editando wikis de tag. Ótimo, isso é bom. Só que nem sempre está com qualidade boa.

Os fragmentos não estão seguindo as diretrizes determinadas pelo SE e que estamos discutindo aqui no meta, especialmente em [Diretrizes para criação de tag wikis](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300/diretrizes-para-criacao-de-tag-wikis).

Estão criando textos curtos, simples, ruins, sem uma mínima formatação, sem o mínimo cuidado com a tradução (ter mais erros em um parágrafo do que eu deixava passar em um texto enorme) e sem citar a fonte, em geral da Wikipedia. Não é uma tragédia, normalmente eu os aceitaria.

Mas essas pessoas não frequentam o meta para saber que estão fazendo algo errado, apesar da boa intenção. Sabemos que frequentar o meta não é muito comum, deveria, mas algo precisa ser feito.

E é pior que essas edições estão sendo aprovadas. Isso é um problema que pode melhorar um pouco (só um pouco) quando sairmos do beta privado (a reputação mínima exigida aumenta mas alguns já estão alcançando a nova reputação também).

Pelo que sei não há nada que possamos fazer diretamente para impedir essas aprovações. E é preciso impedi-las por uma razão básica: as pessoas que estão cometendo os erros não estão procurando se informar se estão acertando e não há como fazermos isso diretamente.

Portanto peço para quem é ativo que tente rejeitar a edição para passar a mensagem correta. **Não podemos aprovar uma edição nota 6 ou 7 (normalmente seria aprovada) de quem comete os mesmos erros e não procura melhorar**. Também não precisa rejeitar porque não é nota 10. precisamos comunicar a essas pessoas que elas precisam revisar seus procedimentos e a aprovação automática que está ocorrendo diz o contrário a elas.

Em alguns casos mais extremos o trabalho de corrigir algo tão pequeno é tão grande que seria melhor outra pessoa fazer a edição por inteiro. Um texto que seja um bom começo, embora longe de ser perfeito ajuda, mas quando ele trás problemas que vão comprometer o entendimento mínimo, ele não pode ser aprovado e ser for (como está acontecendo), alguém terá que editar logo em seguida.

Mas se o aprovador de edições de baixa qualidade se assume a responsabilidade de arrumar os problemas da edição logo em seguida. Aí a aprovação é mais que bem-vinda.

Alguém sugere fazer algo mais para que isso cesse?

Comment: Existe uma forma de ver um registro de atividade das tag? Algo como as edições recentes.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal http://br.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/history acho que é isso que você deseja.

Comment: Acho a pergunta importante e com bom timming. Tenho feito como o bfavaretto refere, sendo generoso, talvez para incentivar e mostrar que contribuír para as tags é bom para a comunidade. Mas concordo que é altura de ser exigente, até porque senão cria má imagem/conteúdo e vai dar trabalho a limpar.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Eu percebi isso desde que os wikis começaram a ser construídos, e tenho feito o seguinte:

- Se a sugestão não for absolutamente terrível e inadequada, ou seja, se eu avaliar que uma edição futura poderia aproveitar parte do conteúdo sugerido, eu aprovo.
- Se eu rejeito uma edição e os motivos "enlatados" não me parecem óbvios para o usuário que sugeriu, eu uso a opção "outros" para explicar o motivo. Quando percebo um mesmo usuário dando várias sugestões equivocadas, procuro incluir alguma orientação em pelo menos uma das rejeições.

Uma coisa que não tenho feito, mas vou começar a fazer, é incluir um link para o meta em certas rejeições.

Em certos casos de edições em perguntas e respostas (mas não wikis) com problemas sérios que acabaram aprovadas, é possível deixar um @comentário para o editor no próprio post, e ele será notificado (detalhe: o autocompletar não oferece o nome do usuário, mas ele será notificado se o @username for composto [segundo as regras](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work)).

Tudo isso são recursos para educar *os editores*, mas o sistema não oferece nenhuma ferramenta para se educar os *analistas*. [Isso é um problema no SO também](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137784/what-can-we-do-to-stop-bad-edits-getting-accepted), ainda sem uma boa solução. Eu mesmo [cheguei a sugerir](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/143491/167534) que os textos de ajuda na ferramenta de análise fossem mais informativos, mas até agora pouco ou nada mudou. Acabei [propondo um faq](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155538) comunitário com diretrizes gerais, que deve estar atingindo *algumas* pessoas, mas ainda não resolve o problema.

---

Acima acabei me perdendo e falando mais de edições em geral do que de tag wikis. Especificamente sobre os wikis, acho o seguinte:

- Como já deixei claro acima, pelo menos neste momento não rejeitaria uma edição a menos que ela tenha problemas sérios (seja absolutamente inútil, ou incompreensível).
- As wikis não precisam estar perfeitas agora, o ideal é que se formem comunidades em torno de cada tag, e que os wikis sejam complementados com o tempo, de acordo com as necessidades de cada comunidade.
- Acho boa a [sugestão do bigown](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/478/aprovacao-de-tags-wikis-sem-qualidade/512#512) de neste momento focar mais nos fragmentos e indicação de uso, mas isso não quer dizer que precisamos parar de editar os conteúdos dos wikis.
- Indicar o uso da tag (no fragmento, e em muitos casos repetindo e desenvolvendo a explicação no próprio wiki) é somente uma das funções dos wikis. A outra é resolver problemas específicos da comunidade em torno da tag. Por exemplo, no SO nas tags de javascript e php (cujo uso é óbvio para qualquer um), os wikis incluem listas de perguntas frequentes sobre essas linguagens, muito úteis a usuários iniciantes que tendem a postar perguntas duplicadas.

Comment: Eu sempre fiz isso, o problema é que é comum o usuário não se dar conta disso. Ele não recebe uma mensagem que a edição foi rejeitada. Mas o pior é que poucas estão sendo rejeitadas, tem 1 voto de rejeição e alguns de aprovação. Quase tudo é aprovado e a pessoa vai achar que está certo. Se fosse um erro eventual, eu aprovaria mesmo estando um pouco ruim. Vária edições minhas foram aprovadas sem estar tão boas. Mas eu venho aqui, debato, leio o que os outros tem a dizer e tento melhorar. Tem pessoas que vão continuar fazendo errado, mesmo tendo boa intenção.

Comment: Quem procurar saber o que aconteceu com suas edições vai ver a mensagem de rejeição, mesmo que o resultado tenha sido uma aprovação. Se o usuário quer feedback, fica mais fácil trazê-lo para a discussão. Existe também a opção de notificar um editor via comentário no post editado, que podemos usar em casos mais graves. E ainda existe gente que nunca vai querer participar das discussões e só quer as medalhas. Paciência. Acho que a tendência daqui para a frente é os analistas sérios serem cada vez rígidos com as sugestões, agora que o conteúdo está ficando mais consolidado.

Comment: Infelizmente parece que alguns não estão olhando suas atividades ou o histórico de análise individual ou global antes de fazer novas aprovações. Em que post você está sugerindo colocar comentário? Nas tag wikis?

Comment: Olha só, [sua pegadinha](http://br.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1422) falhou! :)

Comment: Não foi pegadinha não, me sacanearam :D Foi a troca da tag sem acento p/ acentuada. De fato até vejo motivo para rejeitar mesmo, mas agora ficou com critério rígido demais :) Vou melhorar lá.

Comment: Ué, é exatamente o motivo que você apontou: cópia (de um trecho ruim e obscuro) da wikipedia, e ainda sem referência. Se não fosse obscuro, eu aprovaria ou "improvaria".

Comment: Esqueci por um momento que estávamos falando só de tag wikis, porque existe um problema maior com edições sugeridas que vai além dos wikis (por aqui ainda são poucas, mas tende a piorar). A ferramenta não colabora para se educar os revisores, somente os editores. Veja o último parágrafo que acrescentei há pouco na resposta.

Comment: Não discordo. Eu vi agora que fui traído pelo SO. Lá está uma cópia da Wikipedia sem citação. Porque está obscuro? Tem como editar na hora de aprovar tag wikis? Vamos ter que fazer um esforço nesse sentido e em último caso acionar o Gabe.

Comment: Eu achei obscuro porque a) o trecho era sobre concatenar *conjuntos* de strings; b) era bem formal, sem oferecer um equivalente em linguagem mais coloquial; c) fazia referência a uma seção introdutória, e não fica claro onde está essa seção. Sobre o botão "improve", aparece com 2k rep, quando as edições em wikis não precisam mais de aprovação.

Comment: Sobre "informar o editor", que tal pegar **qualquer** post do mesmo e deixar um comentário pra ele - **apagando** o comentário após um curto período de tempo? (vi isso acontecer com um post meu no SOEN, referido como "poor man's message system" - já que o SE não possui meios dos usuários se comunicarem diretamente, apenas atrelado a uma pergunta/resposta) Dessa forma o editor será notificado - e direcionado à seção relevante do meta - de modo que pelo menos ele não ficará "no escuro"... (se ele decidir ignorar, aí já é com a consciência dele)

Comment: @mgibsonbr Sou a favor do que você sugere, no caso das edições de wiki.

Comment: Concordo com todos, vou me policiar mais para ajudar a ter melhores ações e consequentemente melhorar o conteúdo na nossa comunidade, acredito que depende de cada um ajudar, e não só alguns, o que normalmente é o caso, pois apesar de nao interagir muito no meta, eu acesso comumente, e sempre são os mesmos membros que estão nos debates, deveria haver uma campanha geral pra que todos os usuários no mínimo acessem para que tenham melhor conhecimento do que se passa em nossa comunidade...

Comment: Concordo, @KennyRafael. Sugiro convidar as pessoas para o meta, via comentários, sempre que surgir uma oportunidade (por exemplo, quando alguma pergunta ou edição estiver relacionada a um tópico discutido aqui).

Comment: Não dá para votar mais uma vez depois do edit :)

Answer (score 2):

Meu objetivo primário desta pergunta foi atrair a atenção de todos para um problema pontual mas importante.

Não acho que devemos ser muito rígidos com a aprovação das edições nas tag wikis, apenas evitar que muitas edições ruins se proliferem. A intenção foi apenas deixar claro que o problema precisava ser evitado.

Exigir *qualidade em tag wikis é uma causa perdida*.

Claro que podemos tentar um pouco de qualidade, mas fiz uma avaliação em muitos sites da rede, principalmente os que são ligados ao nosso foco, e o resultado é bem ruim.

A maioria deles mal tem fragmentos depois da segunda ou terceira páginas. Alguns faltam fragmentos na primeira página. E não precisa nem estar em beta ainda, sites graduados há anos estão assim.

O próprio Stack Oveflow deixa muito a desejar em qualidade das tags wikis apesar de ter mais descrições. Proporcionalmente, é até pior.

As wikis mais bem feitas são as que não precisam muito, onde todo mundo acerta no uso. Alguém tem dúvida quando usar [php](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php)? Já [normalização](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/normaliza%c3%a7%c3%a3o) precisa de explicação de qual é o objetivo dela. Alguns casos precisam ficar claros para o que é nosso foco como em [imagens](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/imagens). [depuração](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/depura%c3%a7%c3%a3o) é outro exemplo que pode trazer uso equivocado.

Precisamos nos concentrar nos fragmentos curtos mostrando como a tag deve ser usada, dando definições que ajudem a qualificar melhor o que é a tag, evitando ambiguidades no seu uso. Não adianta muito colocar definição óbvia. Algumas vezes até estraga, embora algumas não cause mal. Mas especialmente não se deve trocar a explicação do uso da tag por uma definição que nada acrescenta. Porém, algumas vezes a definição já explica como a tag deve ser usada.

Principalmente as tags mais usadas precisam de fragmentos.

Os textos principais devem ser usados em tags mais populares para fornecer alguma informação adicional que ajude entender do que se trata e principalmente para facilitar a vida do novato. Deve incluir:

- Definição relevante que ajude entender a tecnologia para o leigo e dê mais subsídios para decidir como usar a tag
- onde obter mais informações básicas e quais são os recursos externos relevantes (livros, manuais, tutoriais, comunidades específicas, onde *discutir* sobre o assunto, etc)
- uma FAQ para evitar que perguntas básicas sejam repetidas como um [*déjà vu* outra vez](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yogi_Berra#Quotes)
- um exemplo introdutório do uso da tecnologia costuma ser útil também

**Alguma coisa é melhor que nada, só precisamos evitar os erros exagerados.**

Comment: Sobre aquelas onde tudo mundo acerta no uso, ver a edição que fiz agora da minha resposta, especialmente o último ponto.