# Como requisitar feedback em edições de wiki de tag?

Tags: debate, wikis-de-tags, filas-de-análise, qualidade

A maioria dos usuários com [relativamente] pouca reputação não pode editar uma wiki de tag diretamente: sua edição precisa ser revista por seus pares, **ainda que** o editor possua reputação suficiente para revisar outras edições. Isso garante uma certa qualidade nas wikis.

Entretanto, a partir de certo ponto (não sei bem qual) as edições passam a ser aplicadas imediatamente. Há uns minutos por exemplo editei [característica-linguagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/caracter%c3%adstica-linguagem) mas não estou seguro que minha edição está boa (os pontos que ganhei perguntando e respondendo não traduzem automaticamente em eu ser um bom redator). Mesmo assim, gostaria de contribuir com algumas das tags faltantes, ainda que não tenha tempo/disponibilidade/saco para me elaborar demais nelas.

Há algum meio de se acompanhar as edições recentes em wikis, de modo que outros possam saber o que está acontecendo sem eu ter que "avisar" cada vez que fizer uma edição aquém do ideal? (a [aba "Ferramentas"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=stats&daterange=today) mostra tags novas, mas não edições recentes em tags) Ou será que eu deveria **me abster** de fazer edições a menos que me disponha a colocar bastante esforço nas mesmas? Simplesmente fazer, e deixar que eventualmente alguém a encontre? Outra coisa?

Answer (score 4):

Procurei e não achei nada sobre ver a lista de edições feitas por quem não precisa de aprovação. Me parece uma falha mesmo.

Acho que tag wikis não estão recebendo muita atenção da equipe porque parece que não há como fazê-las funcionar do jeito que deveria. Por outro lado, como eles não investem mais nelas, não ajudam a resolver o problema.

Eu acho que edições que não estragam, ajudam. Se você faz algum mínimo esforço, já costuma ser suficiente para valer à pena.

Se achar que realmente precisa de feedback, acho que a única forma é pedir aqui no meta. O ideal seria pedir de alguns juntos. Imagine se tivermos uma pergunta no meta para cada tag. Não vai acontecer isso, mas o ideal é não ter perguntas em exagero sobre isso. Duvido que aconteça, mas é bom ter atenção.

Note que alguma edições bem ruins estão sendo aprovadas. Eu mesmo não estou barrando qualquer problema, só os piores. Vide [Aprovação de tags wikis sem qualidade](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/478/aprovacao-de-tags-wikis-sem-qualidade).

Achei o exemplo citado muito bom, melhor que a maioria das tags aqui. E melhor que o equivalente no SO.

Não acho que minha resposta ajude tanto ou seja definitiva, seria bom alguém dizer mais, especialmente se tiver conhecimento de como monitorar todas as edições.

Comment: Outra opção é discutir no chat.