# Como proceder com wiki de tags que não citam fontes?

Tags: debate, wikis-de-tags

Vários wikis de tag estão sendo criadas sem a devida referência ao Wikipedia, nem sempre o revisor se dá ao trabalho de pesquisar para saber se o texto foi retirado de alguma fonte externa e muitas vezes o texto é aprovado.

Hoje por um acaso me dei ao trabalho de procurar um trecho e descobri que ele era cópia idêntica do Wikipedia, como não possuia atribuição de fonte eu acabei rejeitando a wiki, mas sem certeza se isso era a coisa certa a se fazer. Eis o caso:

[Wiki de Tag: server](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7507)
[Servidor - Wikipédia](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Servidor)

O que eu considero ideal não é possível, que seria mandar uma mensagem direta ao criador de wiki de tags pedindo para ele arrumar, pois o mesmo usuário já criou inúmeros diferentes tags sem fontes e estão todas sendo aceitas.

Não estou querendo criticar o usuário que está com a melhor das boas intenções criando inúmeras wiki de tags, pelo contrário, gostaria de avisá-lo pois tenho certeza que não é nenhum trabalho excepcional e tenho certeza de que ele não se importaria de atribuir a fonte.

Além do mais, quem escreveu não leva a culpa sozinho, que aceitou também ajudou a criar uma wiki sem fonte (eu mesmo já aceitei algumas). Apenas alguns exemplos de wikis de tags sem fontes:

[Wiki de tag: Polimorfismo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7428)
[Polimorfismo - Wikipédia](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polimorfismo)

[Wiki de tag: Polígono](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7430)
[Polígono - Wikipédia](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pol%C3%ADgono)

[Wiki de tag: Serial](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7505)
[Interface Serial - Wikipédia](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_serial)

[Wiki de tag: Semântica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7509)
[Semântica - Wikipédia](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sem%C3%A2ntica)

Minhas dúvidas são: Devemos rejeitar como plagio? Ou será que devemos aceitar e logo em seguida atribuir a fonte? E para os inúmeros wikis de tags já criados, devemos buscá-las e sair atribuindo fontes a tudo que for possível?

Relacionado: [Wikis de tag copiados do Wikipédia?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/136/3117)

Comment: Discussões relacionadas: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/300/diretrizes-para-criacao-de-tag-wikis, http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/478/aprovacao-de-tags-wikis-sem-qualidade

Comment: Só para constar, eu li (dinamicamente) as publicações citadas pelo @bfavaretto antes de fazer minha pergunta, entretanto nenhuma delas fala explicitamente o que fazer com esse tipo de publicações, e também nenhuma delas fala o que fazer com as wikis de tags que já foram aceitas e não possuem fonte.

Comment: Sempre é possível usar o "poor man's instant messaging" - deixe um comentário em qualquer post do usuário, apagando-o em breve. P.S. Já alertei esse usuário em particular, e confirmei que ele o leu.

Comment: @mgibsonbr [resolvido](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7613) :D

Comment: Assuntos relacionados: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/480/devemos-indicar-fonte-das-wiki-de-tags-quando-ela-vem-da-tag-do-so-em-ingles e http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/319/o-que-faremos-com-conteudo-de-terceiros-postado-sem-a-devida-citacao

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Devemos rejeitar como plagio? Ou será que devemos aceitar e logo em seguida atribuir a fonte? E para os inúmeros wikis de tags já criados, devemos buscá-las e sair atribuindo fontes a tudo que for possível?

Você já colocou todas as opções na mesa. A resposta vai depender da sua disponibilidade e paciência :)

Viu uma sugestão ruim, sabe a fonte, mas não tem tempo/vontade de melhorar? Rejeite. Tem tempo? Guarde o link e melhore quando for aprovada (só a partir do privilégio "usuário confiável" o botão de melhorar aparece na interface de análise).

Está com tempo e disposição para uma revisão de muitas das tags existentes? Vá em frente!

Comment: `só a partir do privilégio "usuário confiável" o botão de melhorar aparece na interface de análise` eu pensei em citar esse tipo de funcionalidade pois não sabia que já existia. PS: sempre fiquei curioso em saber os privilégios do usuário confiável, aí está um, rs..

Comment: É que para "melhorar", você precisa ter direito de editar wikis sem passar por aprovação de terceiros.

Comment: @Math Já deu pra ver o que você decidiu fazer :D

Comment: Eu vi que você já aceitou alguns :P, mas não to com muita paciência de fazer isso agora não, fiz apenas alguns para passar o comichão, rsrs.. Sempre que puder vou rejeitar como plágio, baita trabalhão voltar consertando tudo. Esse botão de melhorar edição faz uma falta...